# Javascript record webm video with mediarecorder. uploaded to PHP and run through ffprobe: Invalid data found when processing input

Tags: javascript, php, ffmpeg, html5-video, webm

I am capturing local webcam stream (video and audio) via Javascript MediaRecorder (video/webm;codecs=vp8,opus).
I can replay the dataURL object but cannot successfully upload to a php page on the server for downloading at a later stage.

The client code is:

```
return await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
  video: true,
  audio: true
});

startRecording(stream) {
    console.log(`recording started`);
    this._recorder = new MediaRecorder(stream, { mimeType: 'video/webm;codecs=vp8,opus' });

    this._recorder.addEventListener(`dataavailable`, this);
    this._recorder.addEventListener(`stop`, this);
    this._recorder.addEventListener(`error`, this);

    this._recorder.start();
}

async dataAvailable(data) {
    this._data.push(data);
}

async recorderStop() {
    console.log(`recorder stop`);

    this._blob = new Blob([...this._data], { type: "video/webm" });

    this._replay.src = URL.createObjectURL(this._blob);

    this.btn_upload.href = this._replay.src;
    this.btn_upload.download = "clip.webm";
}

async uploadFile() {
    const file_reader = new FileReader();

    file_reader.addEventListener(`load`, async e => {

        const xhr = new XHR();

        const data = { blob: e.target.result };

        const response = await xhr.post_json(`php/video_upload.php`, data);

        if (response.error) {
            alert(`Error: ${response.message}`);
        }
        else {
            alert(`Video uploaded successfully.`);
        }
    })

    file_reader.readAsDataURL(this._blob);
}
```

The PHP file has this:

```
   $data = $_POST['blob'];

$decodedData = base64_decode($_POST['blob']);

$now = (new DateTime('now'))->format('YmdHis');

$filename = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . "video" . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . "uploads" . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . "video_$now.webm";

// write the data out to the file
$fp = fopen($filename, 'wb');
fwrite($fp, $decodedData);
fclose($fp);
```

Running the uploaded file through FFProbe says:

```
ffprobe version 3.4.8-0ubuntu0.2 Copyright (c) 2007-2020 the FFmpeg developers


built with gcc 7 (Ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=0ubuntu0.2 --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librubberband --enable-librsvg --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libopencv --enable-libx264 --enable-shared
  libavutil      55. 78.100 / 55. 78.100
  libavcodec     57.107.100 / 57.107.100
  libavformat    57. 83.100 / 57. 83.100
  libavdevice    57. 10.100 / 57. 10.100
  libavfilter     6.107.100 /  6.107.100
  libavresample   3.  7.  0 /  3.  7.  0
  libswscale      4.  8.100 /  4.  8.100
  libswresample   2.  9.100 /  2.  9.100
  libpostproc    54.  7.100 / 54.  7.100
video_20220219131233.webm: Invalid data found when processing input
```

I have very little knowledge of video/audio encoding but would like to just get the streamed video to be downloadable. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Which of these parts does not work as expected? What have you tried to resolve the problem?

Comment: Perhaps it all works as "expected" in that web captured streaming doesn't have the metadata needed for later download and play. I've tried various ffmpeg copying commands but each of them reports the same "Invalid data found when processing input". I also tried a library "fixWebmDuration.js" but that didn't make any difference. Is this possible at all?